# The back button is not working when a layout is overlayed using WindowManager. How to make it work?

Tags: android

```
LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);

    params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY | WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
    params.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT | Gravity.TOP;
    myview = li.inflate(R.layout.locked_layout, null);
    wm.addView(myview);
```

This is the code I have used for overlaying a layout over a screen. Only the HOME button is working. But the BACK button is not working. I want both to work. Am I missing anything? Please help me!! Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This worked for me!!

```
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);

    WindwoManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(       
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,     
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN |                       
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL | 
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE, PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);      
    params.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT | Gravity.TOP;
```

Comment: The constant `1064` corresponds to `WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE`, and `1` to `PixelFormat.RGBA_8888`. It would be clearer to specify those in the code.

Answer (score 10):

Add this flag as well my friend:

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, you saved my day!

Comment: I need setOnTouchEvent on my View, so how can I slove this problem. thanks!

Comment: Worked like charm :)

Comment: I have it and still app hangs when backbutton is pressed, which is the root of the problem?